# executing code from two files at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, parallel-processing, pygame

I'm creating a programming game with pygame, in which two users write their bots and then the main application executes the code. I'm having real trouble with this idea because it needs to execute them both in parallel while in the background it should be running the main application.

I sorta managed to work around this problem using a queue (appended actions to a list), but in reality it doesn't execute the code in parallel, rather it read the lines from bot A and sends their actions to the queue. Then the other. And then executes both queues, first Bot A and then Bot B. It doesn't work good like this.

I read about async, but i'm not sure how to actually adopt it and make it work. I'm not sure either if that's what I'm looking for or if I need to learn something else.

You can find my code here: https://github.com/WhiteHeadbanger/SpaceWar

If the code is not understandable enough, I'll try to make it better, but I think it's okay

Comment: You must add the relevant code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I understand Rabbid, but the relevant code is all the code. There's no "this part doesn't work".

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). All information relevant to the question should be included in the question itself as formatted text, not in external links or images. The code you've have in the link is not all relevant. In fact, a very large portion seems to be unused or commented away. For you to copy all code into a single file, remove everything unnecessary and place it into the question in a code block is trivial work. It'll greatly reduce the time and effort for people trying to help you, which will give you better answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use threading.

Suppose u have 2 functions, foo and bar. Do

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=foo).start()
threading.Thread(target=bar).start()
```